# How to book a single bus object on different journey dates

Tags: java

Ok so guys I am working on a bus Reservation project on my own.Let me give you a basic idea of what I am trying to do.

Consider I have a Bus Object named 'Bus'. It has basically three methods:

```
           class Bus{
           String date;
           String seat;
           int id;

           public void BookSeats(String seat){

           this.seat=seat

           //code goes for booking seats


            } ;

           public void journeyDate(String date){
            this.date=date
           }

           public void id(int id){
              this.id=id;
          }

         }
```

There are thirty days in a month and the company owns only 3 buses. So there will be three bus objects.
These will be:

```
     Bus A =new Bus ( );


     Bus B =new Bus ( );

     Bus C= new Bus ( );
```

So  if a user called user1 now books a seat named 'A1' of Bus A of id 1 on 25th of October 2019 ( dd/MM/YYYY) then the code should be :

```
    A.BookSeats("A1");
    A.journeyDate("25/10/2019");
    A.id (1);
```

and the seat A1 is booked.

Now what bothers me is that suppose a user called user2 now wants to book a seat named 'A1' of Bus A of id 1 on 26th of October 2019 then 
this code will not be possible since it is the same Bus A object and seat A1 is booked for 25/10/2019 but should not be booked for 26/10/2019

```
  A.BookSeats("A1");

  A.journeyDate("26/10/2019");//same bus A object but different 
  date.

  A.id(1);// same id
```

So as an approach to this problem I wanted to created 30 bus objects for 30 days of a month with 30 unique ids associated with its date. But this is a very bad approach to me. Since the company has 3 bus. So what other approach may I try or other concepts I am missing to tackle the above problem.

Comment: you need to use [collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to be a pretty generic answer, but I feel like it needs more space and formatting than a comment.  Essentially you don't want to use your `class Bus` for managing seats, your `Bus` should only be used for managing what's going on with a bus at a specific time.  For example:

- Number/Plate
- Seats on the bus (once scheduled)
- Departure
- Arrival
- Driver
- Etc

For the purpose of scheduling you want to have a `class Reservation` which should contain all the information about what the bus is going to be on a particular day, such as:

- date
- departure
- arrival
- seat

Which means using your example:

```
User 1 - Reservation(today, Bus 1, Seat A1)
Bus 1 = all reservations for today city A to city B
A1 is empty - fill it.

User 2 - Reservation(tomorrow, Bus 1, Seat A1)
Bus 1 = all reservations for tomorrow city A to city B
A1 is empty - fill it.

User 3 - Reservation(tomorrow, Bus 1, Seat A1)
Bus 1 = all reservations for tomorrow city A to city B
A1 is filled - cannot save reservation
```

You use your Bus to look at an point in time - this should also include time, departure and arrival as Bus 1 seat A1 becomes available on the trip from city B to city A.

This way right now there are three buses, but when they are able to purchase a fourth bus, all that changes is the ability to schedule a 4th departure/arrival pair, which will then be applied to any bus in the fleet.